# Async send parameters to methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, async.js

```
router.post('/historical_data', (req, res, next) => {
  let ramdonName = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(6));
  callRequest(0, 1, 1, 2, true, ramdonName).then((data) => {
    if(!data.error){
        let totalRecords = data.totalRecords;
        let times = Math.ceil(totalRecords / 10000);
        async.timesSeries(times, getHistoricalData).then(endGetHistoricalData);
    }
  });

});

  function getHistoricalData(n, done) {
    // NEED ramdonName
  }
  function endGetHistoricalData(n, done) {
    // NEED ramdonName
  }
```

Where **ramdonName** is a dynamic var I try to sent to method **getHistoricalData** the var **ramdonName**, but the **async.timesSeries** I don't know how to send from another method

Comment: Make both of these higher order functions and then pass `randomName` as a parameter? Add it to the parameter list and partially apply the function?

Comment: Hello, thanks, why i do pass a variable randomName to method getHistoricalData

Comment: @VLAZ How to add to parameter list to apply?

Answer (score 0):

the answer here
use the bind()
getHistoricalData.bind(null, ramdonName)

the firs params on function

```
function getHistoricalData(ramdonName, n, done) {
  console.log(ramdonName); // get the value 
}
```